# Teradata REGEXP_SIMILAR matching exact string

Tags: regex, teradata

I have list of databases and tables obtained like this:

```
SELECT TRIM(DatabaseName) || '.' || TRIM(TableName) AS DatabaseTable
FROM DBC.TablesV t1
WHERE TableKind IN ('T','O','V')
```

I now want to match them to dbc.TablesV.RequestText to build a hierarchy of my database views.
At first i did it with simple join like below

```
JOIN DBC.TablesV t2
ON t2.RequestText LIKE '%' || DatabaseTable || '%'
```

but unfortunately, we have tables like T1010_User and T1010_User_Hist, and databases like `DB_STAGE` and `Q_DB_STAGE` so i decided to add spaces to % to a LIKE clause making it `LIKE '% ' || DatabaseTable || ' %'` but then it fails to get proper results because sometimes tablename is at the end of a requesttext like this: `(...) DB_STAGE.TableName;` and sometimes its like this:

```
(...)
FROM
DB_STAGE.TableName t1
(...)
```

I decided to use REGEXP_SIMILAR to match them with `WHEN REGEXP_SIMILAR() = 1` but my regex-fu is weak, so I cannot build regex that will do something like:

```
((anything other than a letter/number) or nothing) DatabaseTable ((anything other than a letter/number) or nothing)
```

This is to build hierarchy of views to help with migrating data to a different database.

This is very simplified case:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE test1
(
c0 SMALLINT,
c1 varchar(100)
)ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(1,'aaa
Q_abcdef.abcdef');
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(2,' Q_abcdef.abcdef ');
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(3,'aaa
DQ_abcdef.abcdef ');
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(4,' S_abcdef.abcdef');
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(5,'Q_abcdef.abcdefg');
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(6,' sdfs
Q_abcdef.abcdefg');
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(DQ_abcdef,'    7.abcdefg');
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(8,' S_abcdef.abcdefg');
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(9,'Q_abcdef.abcdef;');
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(10,' Q_abcdef.abcdef;');
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(11,'DQ_abcdef.abcdef;');
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(12,' S_abcdef.abcdef;');
```

I need to match 1, 2, 9 and 10. The ones that have string Q_abcdef.abcdef exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\b` for matching *word boundaries*:

```
WHERE REGEXP_SIMILAR (c1, '.*\bQ_abcdef.abcdef\b.*', 'i') = 1
```

This will not return 5 & 6 because it's not matching due to the final `g`

Comment: Oh, my bad. 5 and six are wrong, so that is probably what I want. Thanks a lot (edited main question).